# How to change color theme in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any alternative way to change Eclipse color theme. I found a lot of articles, following the direction step-by-step. However, I could not able to change the color theme because the reason shows as below.

[image]

and

[image]
As a result, I have waited for weeks. but now I still can't change it. I used to Vibrant Ink for a long while and I really love it. May anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website that displays the preview has been down for awhile, however you are still able to select a theme from the list then click "Apply" to apply the theme.

"Download more themes" will not work.

Comment: @steve Do you know, by any chance, why website is still down?

Comment: Not sure. I was thinking of scraping all the themes from internet archive :)